# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "new"

Tags: token

I'm upgrading from PHP 5.5 to 8.1. So far I've made decent progress adding '' around variables such [example] and also replacing __autoload() with spl_autoload_register()

This one currently has me stumped.

This is the code:

`public function __construct() { include_once 'sdb.php'; $this->db = & new sdb;         }`

This is the error:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "new" in /var/www/html/intranet/rma_int/newObjects/jobtime.php on line 143

Anyone see what's wrong please?
Thanks
Tony

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what does ```$this->db = & new sdb;``` mean?  Particularly the additional ```&```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that the sdb class is relying on class that miss the default __construct constructor and have a named constructor instead.